# IIS 6: Enabling Virtual Paths

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, httpmodule

I've developed a simple file browsing HTTP module which uses virtual paths (i.e. paths that do not actually exist on the disk). The app. runs fine on my IIS 7, but on Win 2003 the IIS does not forward the HTTP requests to my Web application - instead it just returns "The page cannot be found" to the browser.

How do I disable this default behavior and allow my Web. app. to process ALL requests on IIS 6, regardless of whether the file is actually disk or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wildcardmapping to the ASP.NET ISAPI engine (you can copy the location from any of the ASP.Net extension mappings), and make sure that "verify that file exists" is not checked.

You can find the wildcardmapping in the virtual directory application configuration.